# How to group rows into output columns, by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in a MariaDB table similar to the following. It is basically weather data at two locations, and I want to feed the data to a stats program. I want to output the data in a way that groups the rows by datetime, but puts the grouped row values into columns.

```
obsv_location   obsv_value    obsv_datetime
-------------   ----------    -------------
airport1        35.0          2020-01-01 12:00
airport2        35.2          2020-01-01 12:00
airport1        36.5          2020-01-01 13:00
airport2        36.4          2020-01-01 13:00
```

Is it possible to create a query that outputs something like the following?

```
obsv_datetime     airport1    airport2
-------------     --------    -------------
2020-01-01 12:00  35.0        35.2
2020-01-01 13:00  36.5        36.4
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: I agree, but there isn't an application to format the display after the query is run. I'm just taking the directly into a stats program.

Comment: "Is it possible to create a query that outputs something like the following?"  Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `join`; another conditional aggregation.  The second:

```
select obsv_datetime,
       max(case when obsv_location = 'airport1' then obsv_value end) as airport1,
       max(case when obsv_location = 'airport2' then obsv_value end) as airport2
from t
group by obsv_datetime;
```

Comment: That sort of works, but all of the values returned are null

Comment: @gregb you can use else or coalesce

Comment: @GregB . . . In that case, the comparison values (`'airport1'`/`'airport2'`) do not match exactly.

Comment: That was it! I wasn't specifying the exact strings. Thank you!